# Не могу понять как работает Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.ValueCollection, для чего и что это вообще

Tags: c#, .net

Увидел данную конструкцию `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.ValueCollection`, начал гуглить, но вещественных примеров не нашел. Хотелось бы узнать для чего это и как с этим работать(желательно на примере).

Comment: А каких вы примеров хотите? `dict.Values`? Ну или `dict.Keys`?) Для чего - ну, иногда, бывают случаи, когда нам не нужны пары "ключ = значение", а нужны чисто либо "значения", либо "ключи", вот вы и можете у словаря попросить только то, что нужно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, желательно для того и другого)

Comment: Для того и другого что? Я вам уже дал пример, все, используйте. Это простое свойство, которое отдает вам коллекцию, я не понимаю в чем у вас трудности? Ну ок, давайте пример так пример сделаю: `var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(){ ["Ключ"] = "Значение" }; string firstValue = dict.Values.First();  foreact(var key in dict.Keys) Console.WriteLine(key);`. Как видите, простая коллекция, работать также, как и с простой коллекцией, что `Keys`, что `Values`, что сам `Dictionary`...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, это я понял, но как мне из этой коллекции взять элемент по ключу? Ведь `dict[key]`  не работает. То есть это будет выглядеть как массив, в зависимости от того что мне надо? Тогда как преобразовать в Dictionary<TKey,TValue>?

Comment: Опять же, я вам дал пояснение по поводу "зачем", повторю "иногда бывают случаи, когда нужны только ключи, ну или только значения, а не целый набор, вот через эти свойства вы можете взять только то, что вам нужно". `взять элемент по ключу?` - из коллекции, которая содержит **только значения**, вы собираетесь что-то взять по ключу? Может индексу? Если да, то преобразуйте в массив, коллекцию, которые поддерживают обращения по индексам и работайте дальше (`string[] arr = dict.Values.ToArray(); string first = arr[0];`). `Тогда как преобразовать в Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` - о чем речь?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я имею ввиду преобразование - от Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.ValueCollection перейти в Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.  То есть это будет выглядеть как `.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)`?

Comment: Да чего вы тут преобразовывать то собрались? Класс `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` (TKey и TValue - это так называемые generic, позволяют делать один класс/метод для разных типов,  через низ вы указываете тип (`Dictionary<int, string>`)) уже содержит в себе свойство `Values`, которое имеет тип `ValueCollection` (который находится в классе `Dictionary`), сама коллекция адаптивная, она в себе содержит сразу тот тип, который вы указали как `TValue`, вам не надо что либо преобразовывать, просто берите и используйте. И еще раз повторю **там только значения!!!!**

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, понял, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Как уже было сказано [evgeniyz](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220553/evgeniyz) данная коллекция содержит в себе все значения в словаре **без привязки к ключу**.

Используется на практике повсеместно, но вот самый простой пример, который приходит на ум: допустим есть метод, который возвращает коллекцию авторов и книг в виде словаря `Dictionary<string, List<string>>()` где `key` - ФИО автора, `value` - список названий книг.

В нашем синтетическом случае мы хотим найти все книги с одинаковым названием, для этого нам потребуется пробежаться только по коллекциям книг и для этого у нас есть возможность обращаться отдельно к **значениям** словаря.

```cs
var authorsBooks = GetAuthorsBooks() // возвращает словарь

// ищем одинаковые названия книг
foreach (var bookNames in authorsBooks.Values)
{
      foreach (var bookName in bookNames)
      {
         // ...
      }
}
```

Так же может возникать и обратная ситуация, когда мы захотим поработать только с ключами словаря.